# Get a value in an array made from JSON

Tags: json, swift

I'm making a request to PHP file which returns me `id = 50`. I want to get only the id.

Xcode forces me to set it as NSArray and the array returns me:

```
(
 id = 50;
)
```

in debug console.

How to get the number in variable?

Comment: Can you post a code.?

Comment: I edited it. I receive in debugger the code that I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you are working with JSON and the way that you've presented your "array return" format, it seems you are working with an `NSDictionary` rather than an `NSArray`. E.g., compare the following examples:

```
let yourNSDictionary: NSDictionary = ["id":50]
print(yourNSDictionary)
/* {
       id = 50;
   } */

let yourNSArray: NSArray = ["foo", 42]
print(yourNSArray)
/* (
       foo,
       42
   ) */
```

To access the value for a given key in an `NSDictionary` instance, followed by performing attempted conversion to an appropriate Swift native type, say `Int`, you can join the two steps

- access the value for a given key just as you would for Swift native dictionaries (`mydict[myKey]`), and
- perform the attempted type conversion

in a optional binding clause:

```
if let id = yourNSDictionary["id"] as? Int {
    print(id) // 50
}
```

Comment: I edited it. I receive in debugger the code that I posted.